# Call specific function from remote PHP in jQuery Validate's remote method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate plugin for field validations on my registration page.

I currently have this code in my validation JS for checking whether the entered username already exists or not:

```
"remote": {
    url: "../assets/php/checkUsername.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        username: function() {
            return $('#register-form :input[name="username"]').val();
        }
    }
}
```

`checkUsername.php` basically returns true or false based on existence of entered username. This works all fine but I want to optimize it.

Now I have `core.php` file that already has function called `account_exists($username)` on it. This function basically returns true or false based on existence of given username as well.

My question is, how can I get rid of `checkUsername.php` altogether and instead use `account_exists` function that is in my `core.php` file?

`core.php` obviously contains a lot more things so I'm not sure how I can tell my validation script to call the specific function from the `core.php`.

Comment: FYI you don't need the anonymous function: `data: { username: $('#register-form :input[name="username"]').val() }`

Comment: could you check with a get at start of the file? `if(isset($_GET['checkUsername'])){ account_exists(); }`

Comment: You send data to the PHP script which tells the PHP script which function you want to use and return information from. You might put your functions in a case statement to facilitate this. `switch($_POST['function']) { case 'username'....` etc.

Comment: JS cannot execute PHP code. you can only do ajax requests to the server, which means you **HAVE** to point your JS code at your .php file.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Is there any way of going about it without altering my core.php? I just want to edit my validation JS.

Comment: Without seeing your core.php it would be hard to know if it needs to be modified or not.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You can just assume that it's bunch of unrelated functions and account_exists function that only takes username and returns true/false. I don't really think there is anything else in the file that could mean anything for this case.

Comment: You're going to have to setup the PHP in such a way that it knows what function is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass another parameter so core.php knows what you want to do

```
"remote": {
            url: "../assets/php/core.php",
            type: "post",               
            data: {
                action: 'check_account',
                username: function() {
                    return $('#register-form :input[name="username"]').val();
                }
            }
        }
```

Of course you will also have to modify core.php so it executes the required code if action=='check_account':

```
if ($_POST['action']=='check_account')
{
...do something...
}
```

Comment: The only problem you have here is you didn't change the data statement properly, so the answer is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, it would work.  See the second example here:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: To the OP of the question and the answer:  You do not need to send the value of the field as part of the `data` parameter since the value of the field being validated  is already being sent by default.